# Play! Framework JPA [RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I have a Question regarding the JPA Usage in Play. 
I have already created a Model Class and annotated it with @Entity, and a Controller Class, in which i have a static method annotated with @play.db.jpa.Transactional. When i start activator run, everything is compiled correctly, and the Database is started, but as soon as the Code where i call the Entity Manager via

```
    EntityManager em =  play.db.jpa.JPA.em();
```

a NullException is thrown.
As far as I am concerned, the persistence.xml and the application.conf is correct, i have already researched the web, but to no avail.
What are possible Solutions for this?
Thanks in advance!

Here is the concrete Piece of code where I use the JPA:

```
public class UserController extends Controller {

@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result registerResponse(){
    System.out.println("registerResponse called!");
    Form<MyUser> regForm = Form.form(MyUser.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (regForm.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("bad request");
        System.out.println("Form: " + regForm.toString());
        System.out.println("Errors: "+regForm.errors().toString());
        return badRequest(views.html.registration.render(regForm,Arrays.asList(Avatar.values())));
    } else {
        MyUser newuser = regForm.get();
        System.out.println("persisting");       

        EntityManager em =  play.db.jpa.JPA.em();  //Here is the Nullpointer exception
        em.persist(newuser);
        System.out.println("persisted");
        return ok(authentication.render(Form.form(Login.class)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add more of the code that you are using? Rather than describe your method and how this is set up, it is more helpful to see the actual code to determine where it may be having an issue.

Comment: added the code where I use the JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you do not need to instatiate this class, you need to use he methods in play.db.jpa.JPA.em()

change this

```
EntityManager em =  play.db.jpa.JPA.em();  //Here is the Nullpointer exception
em.persist(newuser);
```

by this:

```
try {
            JPA.em().persist(newuser);
        }
        catch(PersistenceException pe){
            //the code for the exception
        }
```

with the import `import play.db.jpa.JPA;`